# How many attacks does a bare-fisted level 1 monk make?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, unarmed-combat

If a monk chooses at level 1 to use his fists does he get to make 3 attacks, assuming he uses his bonus action?

1. Right Fist: 1d4 (unarmed strike) + dex
2. Left Fist: 1d4 + no mod for second weapon
3. Bonus Attack Unarmed Strike: 1d4 + Dex

Comment: Also relevant [Can I two-weapon fight unarmed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58157/can-i-two-weapon-fight-unarmed)

Answer (score 7):

They'd get 2 attacks.

TWF uses the bonus action you want to use for the third attack. The monk's martial arts feature *also* uses this bonus action. So it would be:

- Action: Left Fist (d4+dex)
- Bonus Action: Right Fist* (d4+dex) from Martial arts

This allows you to make 2 *full* attacks instead of *just* the attack from the bonus action (that wouldn't otherwise be possible without martial arts because unarmed strikes are not typically light).

*this does not have to be a different weapon, it can be the same fist, a punch or a headbutt or whatever. unarmed attacks are free to be given the flavor you want to give them.